# Программа выводит значение максимального элемента, затем номер строки и номер столбца, в котором он встречается

Tags: c#, массивы

Необходимо выводить максимальный элемент матрицы, затем номер строки и столбца где он находится. Для этого я применил следующую конструкцию *(код ниже)*.

Но код работает так, что он проверяет построчно, и выводит максимальный элемент каждой строки. Подскажите, что я сделал не так?

```
int max = 0;
int maxi = 0;
int maxj = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        if (array[i, j] > max)
        {
            max = array[i, j];
            maxi = i;
            maxj = j;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(max);
    Console.Write(maxi);
    Console.Write(maxj);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` запускайте в конце выполнения **после рутового цикла**, а не внутри

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int max = 0;
int maxi = 0;
int maxj = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (array[i, j] > max)
        {
            max = array[i, j];
            maxi = i;
            maxj = j;

        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(max);
Console.WriteLine(maxi);
Console.WriteLine(maxj);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Как уже сказали в комментариях, стоит вызывать методы Console.WriteLine() после итераций цикла. Ведь все что в блоке с циклом (внутри фигурных скобок) будет выполняться, пока условие правдиво. И вот и выходит, что в вашем коде `max`, `maxi` и `maxj` выводятся после каждой "пробежки" по циклу.

Я бы ещё внес маленькую правку в ваш код, которая позволит чу чуть уменьшить количество сток в Вашем коде:

```
Console.WriteLine(max + "\n" + maxi + "\n" + maxj);
```

Заменит вон те 3 строки с выводом каждого числа.

**Удачи в изучении C#**

### Aqua